# How do I share individual tweets/retweets to Facebook?

Tags: facebook, twitter

I want to share some tweets and retweets to Facebook. The Facebook connect app in Twitter shares every tweet to my Facebook account. I want to be able to control which tweet/retweet gets posted to Facebook and which doesn't.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't share a link to the tweet?

Comment: If you want it automated, you'd need a way to delineate the tweets . . . I can't see any way to do that absent a secondary action like an additional hashtag or something.